# Single-table inheritance using a datetime column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an user class which will handle both registered and unregistered users in our database. I am leaning towards using STI with UnRegisteredUser and RegisteredUser subclasses, but I feel like this is adding some duplication to my code where it's not really necessary.

Right now I'm planing to ad "type" and "registered_at" columns. Really all I need is to define users by whether or not they have a datetime included on "registered_at".

```
Users
  t.string   "type"
  t.datetime "registered_at"
```

This doesn't seem to fit Rails STI convention, but seems like it would alleviate some duplication that is otherwise unnecessary. Does this make sense and how would I build this into my User model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use scopes?

```
scope :unregistered, lambda { where(:registered_at => nil) }
scope :registered, lambda { where("registered_at is not null") }
```

And use them like:

```
User.registered.first
```

**EDIT**

Your subclasses could inherit from `User` and use `default_scope`, e.g.:

```
class UnregisteredUser < User

  default_scope { unregistered }

  # callbacks, etc.

end
```

Comment: I've considered using scopes, but there is quite a bit of difference in functionality between the user types including callbacks where I'd prefer to remove branching. otherwise I'll be making a check against registered_at all over the place. Inheritance feels like the right choice here.